# How to add a blank row to the top of Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

We have a large Google Sheets file where our customer service department adds complaints or mistakes that customers have brought up. We would like them to add each one to the TOP of the document rather than scrolling through to the end. Is there a way to do this?

Ideally, the script will automatically add a new blank row once a row is filled in.

Comment: Take a look at [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)  I might consider using `insertRowBefore()`;

Comment: If you have a last column that always gets filled in when you complete the row then you could use an [onEdit(e) trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit). to insert the row upon editing that column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  var completionColumn=10;
  var topRow=2;
  var editSheet='Sheet1';
  if(sh.getName()!=editSheet)return;//return if not correct sheet
  if(e.range.columnStart==completionColumn && e.range.rowStart==topRow) {
    sh.insertRowBefore(topRow);
  }
}
```